# Nodejs client for twilio video

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-video

I would like to make a nodejs client join a twilio video chat room. When I try to use the twilio client API (the one that is supposed to be used within a browser) it fails because it tried to call getUserMedia but obviously that is not available from nodejs. What is the best way to do this? I would like to have a nodejs client join a video room to get all the feeds and do some processing.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? Also it may be like this issue, `getUserMedia` throws an error unless the URL uses HTTPS or it's localhost: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/177

Comment: the error is follows

(node:67740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TwilioError: Media connection failed
    at MediaConnectionError.TwilioError (/node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/twilioerror.js:37:23)
    at new MediaConnectionError (/node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/twilio-video-errors.js:1146:125)
    at PeerConnectionManager._getOrCreate (/node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/peerconnectionmanager.js:165:17)
    at /node_modules/twilio-video/es5/signaling/v2/peerconnectionmanager.js:233:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Comment: code is - 
  var token = msg.jwtToken
  var roomname = msg.roomName
  Video.connect(token, { name: roomname, audio:false, video:false }).then(room => {
    console.log('Connected to Room "%s"', room.name);